# socket listen() accepting one too many connections

Tags: python, sockets

I'm trying to limit a Python server to only accept a connection from one client, but I'm noticing that the Python server always accepts one too many connections. Here is the server code:

```py
import socket 
import time

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.bind((socket.gethostname(), 1234))
s.listen(0)
clientsocket, address = s.accept()
print(f"Connection from {address} has been established!")
while True:
    time.sleep(1000)
    clientsocket.send(bytes("Welcome to server 1!", "utf-8"))
```

I would expect this to only allow one client connection at a time, since there is not allowed to be any in the queue (`s.listen(0)`). However, I'm finding that this code allows me to connect two clients before getting an error. Here are my clients connecting:

```py
>>> import socket
>>> socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM).connect((socket.gethostname(), 1234))
>>> socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM).connect((socket.gethostname(), 1234))
>>> socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM).connect((socket.gethostname(), 1234))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ConnectionRefusedError: [WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it
```

The first client is accepted, which is expected. The second client successfully connects, which I would not expect since the server already has a connection and 0 connections are allowed in the queue. We do not fail until the third client tries to connect and is denied.

If we up the `listen()` argument to 1, we are allowed 3 connections (1 current, 2 in the queue). If we up it to 2, we are allowed 4 connections (1 current, 3 in the queue). This pattern continues.

How can I specify that my server should allow allow 1 connection and not hold any in the queue?

Comment: Cannot reproduce. Using your code I get a *broken pipe* error on the server side when the client connects.

Comment: Hey sorry I just updated the server side code now. Should work. I was just trying to simplify the code but realized that the way I had it set up, it would immediately try to send data back to a socket that no longer exists since we aren't storing it.

Answer (score 2):

Regardless of the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/socket.html#socket.socket.listen):

> `socket.listen([backlog])`
> Enable a server to accept connections. If backlog is specified, it must be at least 0 (if it is lower, it is set to 0); it specifies the number of unaccepted connections that the system will allow before refusing new connections. If not specified, a default reasonable value is chosen.

Testing indicates the minimum is `1` for **unaccepted** connections, and not `backlog + 1`.  This may be OS-dependent.  I'm using Windows 10.  Note I'm not accepting any connections below, just connecting until they are refused.

```py
In [1]: from socket import *
   ...: for backlog in range(-1,6):
   ...:     s=socket()
   ...:     s.bind(('',5000))
   ...:     s.listen(backlog)
   ...:     c=[]
   ...:     try:
   ...:         while True:
   ...:             a=socket()
   ...:             a.connect(('localhost',5000))
   ...:             c.append(a)
   ...:     except ConnectionRefusedError:
   ...:         print(f'{backlog=} successful_connections={len(c)}')
   ...:
backlog=-1 successful_connections=1
backlog=0 successful_connections=1
backlog=1 successful_connections=1
backlog=2 successful_connections=2
backlog=3 successful_connections=3
backlog=4 successful_connections=4
backlog=5 successful_connections=5
```

Which makes sense.  You need at least one unaccepted connection queued or there would be nothing to `.accept()`.

If you want only one **accepted** connection, call `.accept()` serially and close it before accepting another.  The client can use timeouts if it connects, sends a query and doesn't get a response in a set amount of time.